# Relacionar campos de forma condicional en Pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho

Mi problema es que **no tengo relacionada mi tabla de llamadas con mi tabla de clientes**. Estoy tratando de vincular cada llamada a un cliente, a través del nº de teléfono de llamada y los campos de teléfono que tiene asociado cada cliente ("phone" y "other_phone"). Quiero asociar las llamadas a los clientes de tal forma que:

1. Primero, **busque las coincidencias** de los números de teléfono de la
   tabla de llamadas **por el campo "phone"** de mi tabla de clientes.
2. Segundo, las que no consiga relacionar por el campo "phone", **deberá
   relacionarlas por el campo "other_phone"** de la tabla clientes.

Esto es lo que he tratado de hacer en Pentaho PDI, pero me está funcionando correctamente puesto que solo me está relacionando las llamadas por el campo "phone".

[image: Proceso de Pentaho para relacionar llamadas con clientes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que se ve, en la salida del paso "Filtramos los que encontramos" no tienes bien enlazado el caso de la salida cuando es verdadero.
El enlace a "Buscamos por Other phone" debería de tener el símbolo verde con el check y no el azul de info

Comment: Creo que no es posible el simbolo del check verde cuando lo enlazas con un look up. Sabes cómo podría solventar ese problema?

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo añadiendo un "Select values"